# Working of Insert Delete Get Random O(1) order algorithm with Sets in Python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap, set

While working on a problem I observed something weird about sets. Can someone explain the logic behind it. Whenever I was adding an element to set, it inserted it in correct order. Given that set is an un-ordered data structure, how is this possible?

Following is an example of what I observed:

```html
>>> a = set([1,3,5])
>>> a
{1, 3, 5}
>>> a.pop()
1
>>> a
{3, 5}
>>> a.add(4)
>>> a
{3, 4, 5}
>>> a.add(6)
>>> a
{3, 4, 5, 6}
>>> a.add(2)
>>> a
{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
>>>
```

*How I stumbled across this observation*:

I was tring to solve the problem wherein I have to design a data structure that does insertion, removal and getRandom in O(1) time. The details can be found at https://leetcode.com/problems/insert-delete-getrandom-o1-duplicates-allowed/description/

My basic idea is to use a HashMap of number -> List which stores a list of indexes of all the keys inserted in the list. Along with it I maintain a list(V) of values. List and HashMap will allow for constant insertion. HashMap will allow for constant removal of values. We can achieve constant removal of values from list if we swap the element to be removed with the last element of list and then remove the last element.

Basic use case:

1. To insert a value 1. 1 is appended to the List(V). This index is stored in HashMap with key as 1.
2. To getRandom, an element is picked at random from List(V)
3. To delete, a value 1, the last index of 1 is popped from the HashMap, Then this index is swapped with the new element. Then the last index of the swapped element is updated in the HashMap and the last element in List(V) is removed.

The issue I am facing is that I need to insert the new index of swapped element at the correct position in the HashMap for this algorithm to work.

But interestingly when I use a set in HashMap instead of a list, I do not need to take care of it. The set somehow inserts the element at correct position. I know that set is supposed to be an unordered dataset, then why does this work. Can someone explain this behavior of sets?

The following is a code using lists where I have to use binary search to insert the swapped index at proper position. Here definitely delete in not O(1)

```
    import random
    import bisect
    class RandomizedCollection:

        def __init__(self):
            """
            Initialize your data structure here.
            """
            self.myMap = {}
            self.stack = []

        def insert(self, val):
            """
            Inserts a value to the collection. Returns true if the collection did not already contain the specified element.
            :type val: int
            :rtype: bool
            """
            #print("Inserting",val)
            #print(self.myMap,self.stack)
            tmp = self.myMap.get(val,[])
            if len(tmp) == 0:
                self.stack.append(val)
                tmp.append(len(self.stack)-1)
                self.myMap[val] = tmp
                return True
            else:
                self.stack.append(val)
                tmp.append(len(self.stack)-1)
                self.myMap[val] = tmp
                return False

        def remove(self, val):
            """
            Removes a value from the collection. Returns true if the collection contained the specified element.
            :type val: int
            :rtype: bool
            """
            #print("Removing",val)
            #print(self.myMap,self.stack)
            tmp = self.myMap.get(val,[])
            if len(tmp) > 0:
                if self.stack[-1] != val:
                    idx_to_remove = tmp.pop()
                    last_val = self.stack[-1]
                    #print(idx_to_remove, last_val)

                    self.myMap[last_val].pop() ## removes the last index
                    insert_pos = bisect.bisect_left(self.myMap[last_val],idx_to_remove)
                    self.myMap[last_val].insert(insert_pos,idx_to_remove)

                    self.stack[idx_to_remove],self.stack[-1] = self.stack[-1],self.stack[idx_to_remove]
                    self.stack.pop()
                else:
                    self.stack.pop()
                    tmp.pop()
                return True
            else:
                return False


        def getRandom(self):
            """
            Get a random element from the collection.
            :rtype: int
            """
            return random.choice(self.stack)
```

The following is a similar code using Sets. I am not sure why does this even work.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import random

class RandomizedCollection:

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initialize your data structure here.
        """
        self.nums = []
        self.num_map = defaultdict(set)


    def insert(self, val):
        """
        Inserts a value to the collection. Returns true if the collection did not already contain the specified element.
        :type val: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        self.nums.append(val)
        self.num_map[val].add(len(self.nums) - 1)
        return True


    def remove(self, val):
        """
        Removes a value from the collection. Returns true if the collection contained the specified element.
        :type val: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if len(self.num_map[val]) == 0:
            return False
        index = self.num_map[val].pop()
        last_index = len(self.nums) - 1
        if not (index == last_index):
            last_val = self.nums[last_index]
            self.nums[index] = last_val
            self.num_map[last_val].remove(last_index)
            self.num_map[last_val].add(index)
        self.nums.pop()
        return True


    def getRandom(self):
        """
        Get a random element from the collection.
        :rtype: int
        """
        return self.nums[random.randint(0, len(self.nums) - 1)]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't understand what is the difficulty you are facing. Can you give an example which you think the set should behave differently than in actually does?

Comment: @Michael Veksler - So the way algorithm works is that we know that the last element of a (list or set) for a key in HashMap is the greatest index that key is present at in the list(V). With list when swapping for deletion, you need to insert key at proper position, but with sets we just do an add operation and it works. Why?

What amazed me was that set somehow reordered elements (ascending order) when you added a value that was not the largest. Can someone explain why?

Comment: The element on the set is not last - it is arbitrary. Its order does not matter since all entries with value 5 are equivalent. Preserving the order is not required. The code simply takes an arbitrary entry with value 5, and removes it.

Comment: Look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html at the table explaining `s.pop()`: remove and return an arbitrary element from s

Comment: @ Michael Veksler- Updated the question, please have a look.
I know that pop returns arbitrary elements, but when you insert it set somehow maintains order. That's why the above algorithm works. That is what I am trying to understand.

Comment: It does not always maintain order. There is no guarantee, it just happens often this way at the beginning of the lifetime of the set. The algorithm works with any order. Is your question why sets behave this way, or is it why the algorithm works even when order is randomized?

Comment: It's the second part, why the algorithm works even when order is randomized?
Coz, I tried the exact same thing with lists as shown in post above and it doesn't work until I insert element at proper position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets in python have no guarantee regarding to order. In fact it is common when order is not maintained. For example, on my Python-2.7 and 3.5.2 implementations:

```
>>> a = set([3,10,19])
>>> a
set([19, 10, 3])
>>> a.add(1)
>>> a
set([19, 1, 10, 3])
>>> a.pop()
19
>>> a.pop()
1
>>> a
set([10, 3])
```

Order is sometimes maintained with `set` because this is the way hash-tables work. Usually the `set` starts as a hash table that has `size=a*len(hash_table)` buckets. Element `value` is inserted into bucket number `value % size`. For small and dense integers `value < size`. This means that in such cases `value` is inserted at bucket number `value`, which is the *sorting* order of the values.

This is to show that it should be no surprise when `set` maintains a sorted order in some cases, but this is besides the point. The point is why the `RandomizedCollection` class works.

---

Actually, both implementations of `RandomizedCollection` have the same conceptual data-structure. The `self.stack` of the list-based variant is read and updated in exactly the same way as `self.nums` of the `set`-based variant. They both maintain  a flat list of all elements in the `RandomizedCollection` object.

The list-based implementation uses the fact that `self.myMap[val]` is a sorted list only in `remove()` at:

```
last_val = self.stack[-1]
self.myMap[last_val].pop() ## removes the last index
```

Since `self.myMap[last_val]` is a sorted list of indices, its last element must be the last `last_val` element in `self.stack`. Since `last_val` was taken from the end of `self.stack`, then the last element of `self.myMap[last_val]` is guaranteed to point to `len(self.stack)-1)`. This means that popping the last elements of both `self.stack`  and `self.myMap[last_val]` will keep the data-structure consistent. Other than the above two lines, making `self.myMap[val]` a sorted list only incurs costs. Searching for index in the list is `O(log K)` and insertion is `O(K)`.

The `set`-based solution works on a different order. Instead of removing the index that points to the end of the stack in O(1) by:

```
self.myMap[last_val].pop() # (Sorted list variant)
```

It erases the same element by using O(1) capabilities of `set`:

```
self.num_map[last_val].remove(last_index)
```

The effect is the same. In both cases, the map no longer points to the last element on the stack. There is no need for the `set` to be ordered, only to be able to remove elements in O(1). Eventually, the last element on the stack will be removed by a simple `self.stack.pop()` or `self.nums.pop()`.

Sometimes it is not the last element that had to be removed, but the code removed it anyway. The idea is to then remove the *correct* element, and put the "wrongly" removed element in its stead. The solution with the sorted list works hard in O(K) to reinsert the removed element:

```
insert_pos = bisect.bisect_left(self.myMap[last_val],idx_to_remove)
self.myMap[last_val].insert(insert_pos,idx_to_remove)
```

In the case of the `set` this is quite simple, since no order is required:

```
self.num_map[last_val].add(index)
```

And finally, the array that contains the actual values (`self.nums` and `self.stack`) is updated so that the last element is finally removed, and reinserted instead of the element that should have been removed in the first place.

---

To summarize, both data-structures are equivalent. In one, the set of indexes is maintained as a sorted-list and in another as `set`. The code in the sorted-list variant sometimes takes advantage of the fact that the list is sorted, in order to remove the largest element in O(1). However, for the `set` case no such optimization is required, since removing any element is O(1), and `remove()` can be used instead of `pop()`.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. I missed the part where removal was O(1) from sets.